# how to prove group or not using associative law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, associativity

Let
 G=(a,b)*(c,d)=(a+bc,bd),
 how to prove this is associative or not .i want to prove this is a group using associative law

Comment: Do you want to prove this is a group or that the  associative property stands? If it's the latter then just multiply 3 terms with with different associations (x*y)*z and x*(y*z) and check if they match

Comment: "*I want to prove this is a group* **using** *associative law*"  To prove that something is a group requires proving several things about it, not just this one property by itself.

Comment: G = ... :is incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

When F is a field, F×F with the operation
(a b)*(c,d) = (a ÷ bc, cd) is not a group because
(0,1) is the identity but (a,0) does not have an inverse.

Perhaps you mean (a, b)*(c,d) = (ad ÷ bc, cd), b,d /= 0,
the standard construction of the rationals from the integers.

The statement of the problem is vague and confusing for lacking needed details.